# Symfony update related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets say we have Employee registration system. We have four entities: Employee, Login, Phone, Email
One Employee has Many login,s, Many Phones and ManyEmails

I have created LoginType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password');
}
```

Then Phone type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('phone');
    }
```

Email Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder
        ->add('eMail') ;
}
```

And Finally Employee type, what ties all of them togheder, plus some extra fields:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('middleNames')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('dateofbirth', 'date', array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'read_only' => true
            ))
            ->add('address')
            ->add('idcode')
            ->add('position')
            ->add('phone', new EmployeePhoneType(), array('data_class' => null))
            ->add('email', new EmployeeEmailType(), array('data_class' => null))
            ->add('login', new LoginType(), array('data_class' => null))
            ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

In ORM all entities have relations

```
  class Employee {
    /* ...Other fileds not shown here...*/

    /**
    * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $login
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AuthBundle\Entity\Login", mappedBy="employee", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    protected $login;
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $phone
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\EmployeePhone",  mappedBy="employee", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $email
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\EmployeeEmail", mappedBy="employee", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $email;

    }


class EmployeePhone{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="phone", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $employee;
}

class EmployeeEmail{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="email", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $employee;
}
class Login{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Crm\AdminBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="login", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $employee;
}
```

Now when i do the updtade action i first load employee object in controller:

```
$employee = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Employee')
            ->find($empId);
```

And then initiate form and tie $employee with form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new EmployeeType(), $employee, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('employee_save')
        ));
```

The problem $employee object itself is correctly loaded and displaied in form fields, but all releated objects are shown as  object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[416] and no data is retrived. Even if i do initialize() for those PersistentCollections, then data is shown under coll atribute, but not displayed in form.

How to do thos update action correctly ?

Comment: Have you tried setting dataclass to the correct type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [collection field-type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) for a one-to-many relation between `Employee` and `Phone`/`Email`/`Login`

Answer (score 0):

Yes collection type field would have been best choice in this case, but since i realized that application actually needs fixed number of phone and e-mail fields, then i removed separate entity and saved fixed number of entries into main entity. Also fixed data_class to correct one.